# Submitbutton does not have the same length as the input field in iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios, webkit

I want my textfields and a button to span the whole size of the screen, however the textfields and the buttons do not have the same length even though they're using the same CSS selector.

This is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/AakN4/2/

In safari the difference is less big but still visible.

### Result

Left with a defined pixel-width
Rigth with a width of 100% (The textfields should have the same length as the button).

http://i.minus.com/jUbh0W0aVWFMl.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define **box-sizing** to your input. Write like this:

```
input {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 15pt;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/AakN4/4/

The reason of the difference is that `input type="submit"` working like `box-sizing` by default. It's include `padding & border` to it's totally `width` & `input type="text"` add `padding & border` with it's totally `width`.

Comment: This works like a charm. So that means that the outer box of the control is used for its sizing? Since this will run inside a native app I can even remove the two -[...]-box-sizing directives.

Comment: Yes, you can remove the two directives.